# Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository <repositorio> was added by build file 'app\build.gradle'

Tags: android, android-studio

Inicié un nuevo proyecto en Android Studio, la cuestión es que necesitaba implementar una librería llamada *android-image-cropper*, a lo que ya me dieron la solución que era actualizarlo a la última versión.

Después de ello se presentó el siguiente error:

> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'MavenRepo' was added by build file 'app\build.gradle'

Dice exactamente dónde está el error, pero soy principiante y no sé muy bien qué hacer. Les añado el código y la descripción del error.

Descripción del error:

```
    Build file 'C:\Users\Blader\AndroidStudioProjects\DomiciliosBlader\app\build.gradle' line: 32
    
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    > Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'MavenRepo' was added by build file 'app\build.gradle'
```

Ahora añado el código donde me presenta el error y, para dejar claro, el archivo es el *build.gradle(project:el_nombre_de_mi_proyecto)*

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
    
    android{
        compileSdk 30
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.domiciliosblader"
            minSdk 19
            targetSdk 30
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled = true
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        allprojects {
            repositories {
                mavenCentral()
                maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:20.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        //implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
        implementation 'com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.2.0'
    }
```

Comment: Ya editaron tu pregunta, de todas maneras: no coloques datos sensibles en la pregunta, es muy buena carnada para los spammers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Es por que todo esto
    
    
    
    
    allprojects {
                repositories {
                    mavenCentral()
                    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
                }
            }





Hay que ponerlo en gradle a nivel de proyecto.
```